# "watching" a log on FreeBSD vs Linux

Tags: linux, freebsd, logging, grep, tail

On Linux systems I can

```
watch -n1 tail /var/log/whatever.log
```

or

```
watch -n1 grep somestuff /var/log/whatever.log
```

To show updates to a log every 1 seconds.
On FreeBSD however, the *watch* command does something else entirely. Who knows a good FreeBSD command for what I'm  trying to do? =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about this: `$ tail -f logfile`?

And if you need to grep: `$ tail -f logfile | grep foobar`.

Comment: On linux you generally have "tailf" which has the advantage of "not accessing the file when it is not growing".

Answer (score 8):

```
Port:   gnu-watch-3.2.8
Path:   /usr/ports/misc/gnu-watch
Info:   GNU watch command
Maint:  ehaupt[ woof-woof ]FreeBSD.org
B-deps: 
R-deps: 
WWW:    http://procps.sourceforge.net/
```

Answer (score 4):

- Linux: `watch -n 5 tail /var/logfile`
- Freebsd: `cmdwatch -n 5 /var/logfile`
- Openbsd: `gnuwatch -n 5 /var/logfile`

(Install from Ports for the BSDs)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a quick shell loop:

`while sleep 1; do clear; grep somestuff /var/log/whatever.log | head -n 18; done`

Answer (score 2):

If I define your "what I'm trying to do" as "watch changes to a log file", I would suggest rather than using `watch` that you could just use the "-f" (for "follow") or "-F" option on the `tail` command, as in `tail -f /var/log/whatever.log`.  The output can also be piped through grep to give you the filtered version you show there.  I believe this is also likely to be more efficient than "watch".

**Edit:** I thought the "follow" option wasn't available on BSD but it appears it is.  Must have been thinking of something else that's not there...

Comment: There are the same `-f` and `-F` options to [tail](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tail&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE) on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script for all things that you want to do with watch command.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do
clear
date
echo ------------------------------------
eval "$@"
sleep 2
done
```

Usage:sh scriptname.sh 
example:sh scriptname.sh ls -l

Comment: You are missing `"` around `$@` and `eval` is not needed. `[ 1 -lt 2 ]` could be replaced with `true`. Your script would be a lot more readable if you used some indentation.